# Error in BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml

Tags: blackberry

I've installed Blackberry Java plugin 1.3.0.

When I create a new project `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml` shows error.

What is the problem? Is there any environment path problem? If yes, what should to set path?

Comment: **What** error does it show? And what leads you to believe that the problem is somehow related to the path?

Comment: Before BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml, the error image (x) has been shown. When i execute, Error exist in required project. Problem isn't in my coding.

Comment: And what does Eclipse show in the Problems view when the XML file is active (i.e. open it and check the Problems view, if you can't find it, select Window -> Show View -> Problems).

Comment: The error is InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'.' at column '{2}'.

Comment: what is your jre version

Comment: go to windows->preferences->java->installed jres

Comment: Xml file created automatically, i couldn't change anything. but still its throws that error.

Comment: jre 6.0. I've install full blackberry java plug in 1.3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression
you should of course follow the hint in the error and check that none of your values in your BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml will fail the regex.

However, there is a very strange case whereby you will see this error regardless of your values. In fact, creating a new project straight from Eclipse will still show the error.

Turns out this could be caused by having Java JRE 7 installed on your machine. The BlackBerry plugin doesn't support this yet, Eclipse might be trying to use that.

The fix? You simply have to edit the eclipse.ini that will live in the same directory as your eclipse.exe that you use to start the IDE. Closing Eclipse and making a backup of eclipse.ini before you do this would be a good idea.

Find the line "openFile" and immediately after, add the following:

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/javaw.exe [or wherever your jre6 directory might be]

Cross your fingers and restart Eclipse.
Rebuild your projects.

Comment: Hi , i follow your instruction. but still its not cleared. In my machine, jre7 also installed.

Comment: In eclipse, window->preference->java->build path->classpath variables->jre_lib(non-modifiable,deprecated)-C:\programfiles\java\jre7\lib\rt.jar

Comment: Hi, the error has resolved. Thank u very much. and one more thing, my system os is windows server 2008, but in blackberry update site, technical requirements is  Windows® XP or Windows 7, if i update 7 is is working ?

Comment: my system os is windows server 2008, but in blackberry update site, technical requirements is Windows® XP or Windows 7, if i update blackberry JRE_7,  is it working ?

Comment: My friend system has same os (windows server 2008). when he open the 9930 simulator, it gives error - Error - JVM - BlackBerry 9930 Simulator  JVM: could not open D:\BB_Eclipse1_1\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_7.0.0.21\components\sim‌​ulator\Java\net_rim_bis_lib.cod

Comment: when i execute the program, C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar(java/io/UTFDataFormatException.class): Error!: Duplicate definition for 'java.io.UTFDataFormatException' found in: java.io.UTFDataFormatException
Packaging project G_Sample failed (took 2.071 seconds)

Comment: are u uninstalled jre7.if u removed jre7 also delete path in environment variables

Comment: the idea is right, but you have also to uninstall jre7 and restart os. Thanks for the hint, it works well :)