# Error while creating a blackberry Project

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to create a new BlackBerry project in eclipse using Jre as BlackBerry 5.0.0.
While creating the project, am getting the following error :

```
InvalidRegex: Pattern value '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'.' at column '{2}'.
```

But i can't find any special character like '-' this in the specified xml file.

It was working at the first time when i had installed the blackberry plugin in eclipse..after that this error is getting when am trying to create a new Blackberry project ..

Can anyone tell an exact solution.?

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468655/error-in-blackberry-app-descriptor-xml it may help you

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729802/error-in-xml-file-while-creating-a-project-in-black-berry

Comment: thanks...after uninstalling jre7 from my machine this issue gets solved..

Answer (score 0):

Better make sure that there are no spaces given.

Comment: that i already checked..there are no spaces or special characters in xml.